# How can I test a stored procedure when it is concurrently called?

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, sql-server-2008-r2, nunit

How can I test a stored procedure when it is concurrently called?

Preferably in NUnit, but if another test harnesses handles this better, I'd use it